# React native key not updating properly in for-loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, firebase, react-native

I have a function in my React-native app in which I loop through keys in an array and pull the respective ref from Firebase.

However, within my for loop, although the proper ref is always evaluated, the key value inside the for-loop itself is always 3, and therefore `totalItemsCompleted` (which is equal to the length of the key's value in `userItemsArray`) is always equal to 3.

```
 listenForItems(itemsRef) {
    var userItemsArray = {
        0: [1],
        1: [5, 6],
        2: [8, 9, 10],
        3: [11, 12, 13]
    };

    var pastItems = [];
    var currentItems = [];

    for (var key in userItemsArray) {
        console.log("KEY1 " + key); //key is correct here
        var itemRef = itemsRef.child(key);
        itemRef.on('value', (snap) => {
            var totalItemsOnList = snap.val().items.length;
            var totalItemsCompleted = userItemsArray[key].length;
            console.log("KEY2 " + key); //key is always 3 here
            if (totalItemsOnList===totalItemsCompleted) {
                pastItems.push({
                    title: snap.val().title,
            });
            }
            else {
                currentItems.push({
                    title: snap.val().title,
                });
            }

            this.setState({
                currentItems: this.state.currentItems.cloneWithRows(currentItems),
                pastItems: this.state.pastItems.cloneWithRows(pastItems)
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderfull world of asynchronous programming. Your for loop isn't waiting for the firebase call to finish so it keeps updating the key value. Can you try to do a console.log(snap.name()) instead of the key?

Comment: @AndréKool aha! That's right; I am now using snap.key() and getting the correct value (snap.name() is being deprecated soon). Thanks so much!

Comment: Great, i will add it as an answer so it can help other people when they also run into this problem. And i was doubting between name and key and i just took the first one i found on google search :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the asynchronous nature of firebase. Your for loop isn't waiting for the firebase call to finish so it keeps updating the key value.

Insead of using the key variable you should use the key of your firebase snapshot like this:

```
var itemRef = itemsRef.child(key);
    itemRef.on('value', (snap) => {
        var totalItemsOnList = snap.val().items.length;
        var totalItemsCompleted = userItemsArray[snap.key()].length;
        console.log("KEY2 " + snap.key());
```

Answer (score 1):

The same flow can be easily reproduced with next code:

```
for(var i= 0; i< 3; i++) setTimeout(()=> alert(i) ,i * 1000)
```

Although you are creating several instances of anonymous function it is not locked onto appropriate `key` value but refer to its 'by name' instead.
So where any of handler invoked variable `key` contains the last value it've got during the loop.

There are different ways to deal with it.
The simplest one is to wrap handler's creation into self-invoked anonymous function:

```
temRef.on('value', ((keyFixedValue) => {
return (snap) => {/*all other code*/}
})(key))
```

Another possible way is about storing `key` as attribute value of appropriate HTML element