# Backbone Firebase Asynchronous call and promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, backbone.js, firebase

I am trying to fetch data from Firebase to display a chart. The promises seems to work fine when I individually enter the url instead through the for loop. When I use the for loop, the ref is not updating and week[i] is undefined. Once the xaxis array is filled, I will be calling another function to display a chart. I am very new to asynchronous callbacks and any direction/hint will be greatly appreciated. I am wondering why week[i] is undefined within the callback?

EDIT: Looks like the for loop runs fully first and then firebase is loaded. So, value of i will be 6 by the time firebase is loaded and ready to go.

```
var xaxis = [];
        var week = [582016, 592016, 5102016, 5112016, 5122016, 5132016, 5142016];
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            var total_day_calories = 0;
            var ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/"+ week[i] );

            ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){

                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

                    var childData = childSnapshot.val().total_calories;
                    total_day_calories = total_day_calories + childData;
                });

                xaxis.push(total_day_calories);
                console.log(xaxis);
            }, function(errorObject) {
                console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982331/react-native-key-not-updating-properly-in-for-loop/36983238#36983238) question and the answer i posted there. I think it's practicly the same issue

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for your response, will take a look at your answer. I kind of fixed it by calling the for loop after firebase is loaded and everything works well for now.